# How to make the browser remember the last page shown in multi-tab paginated content generated via ajax and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser

I have a tabbed content. based on the HTML below:

```
<ul class="tabContainer">
</ul>

<div id="tabContent">
     <div id="contentHolder">
        <!-- The AJAX fetched content goes here -->
     </div>
   <div id="pagination"></div>
</div>
```

f_tab is the function that manages the content of this above HTML,including actions below:

- generating tabs.
- executing AJAX that fetches the php pages and return the result in the tab holder.
- paginating each content inside the content holder using jPaginator plugin (https://github.com/remylab/jpaginator):

  ```
   function f_tab(str){
  $(document).ready(function(){

          var Tabs = {
          '1' : 'page1.php?p='+var,
          '2' : 'page2.php?p='+var,
          '3' : 'page3.php?p='+var,

      }


   var topLineColor = {
      blue:'lightblue',
      blue:'lightblue',
      blue:'lightblue',}


  $.each(Tabs,function(i,j){

      var tmp = $('<li><a href="" class="tab">'+i+' <span class="left" /><span class="right" /></a></li>');


      tmp.find('a').data('page',j);


      $('ul.tabContainer').append(tmp);
  })


  var the_tabs = $('.tab');

  the_tabs.click(function(e){

      var element = $(this);


      if(!element.data('cache'))
      {   

          $.get(element.data('page'),function(msg){
              $('#contentHolder').html(msg);
              element.data('cache',msg);
          });
      }
      else {
      $('#contentHolder').html(element.data('cache'));

      }
      e.preventDefault();

  })

  the_tabs.eq(2).click();    });       return false;        }
  ```

The pagination function (just for information) is:

```
 (function($){

    $.fn.extend({ 
        MyPagination: function(options) {
            var defaults = {
                height: 600,
                fadeSpeed: 1000
            };
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            //Creating a reference to the object
            var objContent = $(this);

            // other inner variables
            var fullPages = new Array();
            var subPages = new Array();
            var height = 0;
            var lastPage = 1;
            var paginatePages=null;
            var numero=0;

            // initialization function
            init = function() {
                objContent.children().each(function(i){
                    if (height + this.clientHeight > options.height) {
                        fullPages.push(subPages);
                        subPages = new Array();
                        height = 0;
                    }

                    height += this.clientHeight;
                    subPages.push(this);
                });

                if (height > 0) {
                    fullPages.push(subPages);
                }

                // wrapping each full page
                $(fullPages).wrap("<div class='page'></div>");

                // hiding all wrapped pages

                objContent.children().hide();


                // making collection of pages for pagination
                paginatePages = objContent.children();


                numero=$(paginatePages).length;

                // show first page
                showPage(lastPage);

            };



            // show page function
            showPage = function(page) {
                i = page - 1; 
                if (paginatePages[i]) {

                    // hiding old page, display new one
                    $(paginatePages[lastPage]).hide();
                    lastPage = i;
                    $(paginatePages[lastPage]).fadeIn(options.fadeSpeed);

                }
            };

            // show pagination function (draw switching numbers)

            // perform initialization
            init();


            //$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#pagination").jPaginator({ 
                nbPages:numero,
                marginPx:5,
                nbVisible:8, 
                overBtnLeft:'#over_backward', 
                overBtnRight:'#over_forward', 
                maxBtnLeft:'#max_backward', 
                maxBtnRight:'#max_forward', 
                onPageClicked: function(a,num) {

                    showPage(num);
                } 
            });
            //});

        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**Question:**
 How can I make the browser rememeber the last shown page in a tab while passing from a tab to another. For example, if the last page shown in tab1 is page5, after clicking on another tab and then returning to tab1, how can I see page5 of tab1?

Thank you for your time. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are AJAX loading each of the tabs, it loses all state information.
As far as I see it, you have the following options:

1. Don't AJAX load the tabs. This would mean a longer load time for the page but less wait between changing tabs.
2. **IDEAL:** Change your tab change function to check if the content has already been loaded. Only AJAX in the content if it hasn't already been done.
3. Save the page state in a variable and change the page to the variable value every time the tab is loaded.

Comment: 1. is not possible. I think (if I understand you well) that 2. is alreay perdormed via 'cache' 3. is the solution in my case and I am now doing my best to implement it. Thank you for the time you gave to my beginner question.

Comment: I think, `cache` is caching the original data and re-adding the data. I am suggesting that you use the original content in a `div` (keep it hidden when switching away from it). This would be preferable to solution 3.

Comment: I opted for option 3 using history.js and keeping my ajax functions as they are.